# vbscript to get exe location and add to registry key

Tags: vbscript

Need assistance in creating vbs. I have exe which can be executed from anywhere. so i need to get the exe location and add to registry entry.

Ex: location of exe : c:\abc\execute.exe
registry location : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Persisted

Add key as c:\abc\execute.exe dword=1

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this, if I am understanding your question correctly.

To call this script, you would simply go to the Start menu, and type into the search box (or run box):

```
cscript {path-to-your-script\scriptname.vbs} /filepath:"C:\abc\execute.exe"
```

You would need to replace `{path-to-your-script\scriptname.vbs}` with the full path and filename of the script example provided below. Remember to save the code snippet with a .vbs extension.

This vbs snippet will silently add C:\abc\execute.exe with a dword value of 1 under the key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Persisted if the registry path exists and the executing account has sufficient permissions to do so.

*NOTE: This script snippet will not work on older versions of Windows as wscript.arguments.Named.Item is not supported.*

```
    ' cscript <scriptname.vbs> /filepath:"C:\abc\execute.exe"

    Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001


    filePath = wscript.arguments.Named.Item("filepath")
    Value = 1

    strComputer = "."
    Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
    strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Persisted"

    if filePath <> "" then 
        objRegistry.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, filepath, Value
    end if
```

Hope that helps.